# Disabling an HTML.TextAreaFor in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, textarea

I have a C#.Net  MVC3 web app and we use HTML.TextAreaFor() text areas for editting and display.  In one instance it should be edittable and in another it shuold be display only.  How would I accomplish this?  Is there another element I should use or can I make the TextAreaFor disabled?
Also,  the TextAreaFor needs to word wrap in the display only mode as well...it's in a grid cell

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just use the `htmlAttributes` parameter:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Something, new { @readonly = true })
```

To tidy up the `if` / `else` in your View, use an extension method which does the if check and renders out the different textbox.

Not sure what you mean about word wrapping - from my understanding `<textarea>` elements always wrap, unless you use `wrap="off"`

Answer (score 2):

For the second part of your question, you can turn off wrapping like so:

```
  @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Name, new { wrap = "off" })
```